# Div don't stack without additional clearfix in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float, clearfix

I am relatively new to bootstrap and created a first main page with a big jumbotron and 3 horizontally aligned columns below. All include one image and text below. See code here:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-billboard">
<div class="img">
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
        <h1>Text in jumbotron</h1>
        <p>Text below jumbotron</p>
        </div>
        <p id="center"><a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="about" role="button">Contact us »</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 block-margin clearfix">
       <h3>Header 1</h3>
        <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/cjribbons/img/1.jpg" class="image-main">
      <p class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 block-margin clearfix">
       <h3>Header 2</h3>
        <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/..../img/2.png" class="image-main">
      <p class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 block-margin clearfix">
       <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/.../img/3.jpg" class="image-main">
      <p class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </div>

</div>
```

I would want to stack the three columns vertically for tablet and mobile, and since bootstrap offers a floated layout, I was under the impression this would happen automatically since the container class is responsible for clearing the float of its children.

In the code, I still needed to use clearfix for every column to let the blocks stack for mobile and tablet.

I am assuming it has sth to do that I put the images to float left and the container clearfix just reaches direct descendants, which are the columns?

I might be thinking in a totally wrong direction and need some light.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use clearfix on the columns. Make sure another CSS class such as `block-margin` isn't effecting the columns. Also use `img-responsive` on the images so the don't overflow the columns.

https://www.codeply.com/go/3yiM4FjysI

Comment: Many thanks!! I think I am now clearer about what I actually want: On tablet view, I would like to have the text on the right next to the images and not pressed to the bottom, which is what the clearfix reaches.

Comment: I let the image float left for exactly the tablet dimensions. I hope that is correct. Apologies for double post.